# assertExists with if-else statement

Tags: javascript, testing, casperjs

I use this code:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
...
casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_13_1')]"), function() {             
    this.test.assertExists(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_13_1')]"), 'Clickable');
    this.click(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_13_1')]"));
});
```

I am trying to use `if-else` with `assertExists` to click another element if the first is not there:

```
casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_13_1')]"), function() {          
    if(this.test.assertExists(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_13_1')]")==="PASS"){
        this.click(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_11_1')]"));} 
    else{
        this.click(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_22_1')]"));
    }         
});
```

But that does not seem to work. How would one do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what `casper.exists()` is for. You can also explicitly pass or fail some things:

```
casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_13_1')]"), function() {          
    if(this.exists(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_13_1')]")){
        this.test.pass("Clickable");
        this.click(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_11_1')]"));
    } else {
        this.test.fail("Clickable");
        //this.click(x("//a[contains(@id,'cell_22_1')]"));
    }       
});
```

This code is equivalent to your first snippet. Comment the `fail()` call and uncomment the last click in order to get your "intended" behavior.

Btw, it doesn't make sense to fail some assertion and still continue with the script. You have to think about what exactly you want to test and what part of your script is supposed to be navigation to the component under test.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it does not work if `a[contains(@id,'cell_13_1')]` does not exist...

Comment: But this works :) `if(!casper.exists('#selector')){
   #selector doesn't exist
}` and so on :)